Are there "bulk move functions" in C++ that avoid multiple move assignments just like std::memmove avoids multiple copy assignments?
I was reading about std::copy on cppreference, and they say most standard libraries will use std::memmove if you have a contiguous range and the elements are trivially copyable. This is apparently much faster than copying things one by one, as you can just copy all the memeory in a "single blast" according to Stephan T. Lavavej (an STL implementer).
Say I have a range that meets those same requirements, like std::vector<int>, and I want to move my range to another std::vector<int> using std::ranges::move. Does this algorithm move elements one by one, or does it do the same check as std::copy and move everything in one operation? Is there any function analogous to std::memmove that does this? If there isn't, would such a function be useful?

For trivially copyable types, std::copy probably uses std::memmove.

@Eljay Yes, that is what I said. What do you mean?

In practice, for trivially copyable elements, std::copy() will probably use std::memmove() (move all in a "single blast") - but it depends (it is really a quality of implementation concern, not a law of nature).   That said, it would not be difficult to code up (specialise std::copy() for trivially copyable types) so I would be surprised if a quality implementation of the standard library (it's no longer called the STL, BTW - you're only 20 years or so out of date in nomenclature) would do anything different.

Yes, that is what I said. What do you mean?  Ahh, well, then I don't understand why you are asking the question then.  All good.

@user4581301 It's almost like he was destined for the job.

@user4581301 he actually changed his middle name to Thomas so that his initials would be STL. Source: cppcast

That makes it funnier.

If a type is trivially copyable, then a move and a copy are the same operation. It is only for non-trivially copyable types where a distinction needs to be made. Given a contiguous range of trivially copyable types, the std::move algorithm is permitted to use std::memmove in its implementation.
